# Find the density function of T= max(X,Y)

Tags: probability, exponential-function, uniform-distribution, density-function

I have some problems about this question.

> $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables: X is an exponential
>   random variable, Y is a uniform random variable over $[0, a]$. Given
>   that $EX = EY = 6$, find the density function of the random variable
>   $T = max(X, Y ).$

Now, I found that $a=12$, $f(x)=1/12$ when $0 < x < 12$  ($0$ otherwise), and $\beta = 6$. I solved some problems similar to this but the distributions were not different. So honestly I do not know what to do to find the density function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your title disagrees with your question (min in the title, max in the question).

Comment: @parsiad I edited thanks or noticing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $F_{Z}$ be the cumulative distribution of a random variable
$Z$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then
\begin{multline*}
F_{T}(t)=\mathbb{P}\{T\leq t\}=\mathbb{P}\{\max\{X,Y\}\leq t\}=\mathbb{P}(\{X\leq t\}\cap\{Y\leq t\})=\mathbb{P}\{X \leq t\} \mathbb{P} \{ Y \leq t \}\\=F_{X}(t)F_{Y}(t).
\end{multline*}

Comment: And to find the pdf should I take the derivative of $F_X(t)F_Y(t)$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: in each case right? e.g. when $t<0, 0<t<12$ and $t>12$

Comment: You can avoid the case of $t < 0$ altogether since $T$ has support $[0,\infty)$. But as you point out, there is a point of nondifferentiability at $x = a$. As such, you can handle the case $x < a$ and $x > a$ separately.